# How do I center the navigation bar in my website?

Tags: css

I'm using Weebly to create a website, and I've been trying to modify the navigation bar so that it appears centered rather than left justified. I don't really know any code at all, but I found the navigation code, and I was wondering what I could change to center the bar. Thanks!

```
#nav-wrap .nav {
float:left;
}

#nav-wrap .container {
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background:url(saperator-h.png) repeat-x bottom;
padding-bottom:40px;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul {
list-style: none;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
background:url(nav-saperator.png) no-repeat right center;
margin-right: 10px;
padding-right: 25px;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul > li:last-child, #nav-wrap .container ul span:last-child li {
background:none;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li a {
display: block;
line-height:14px;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding:5px;
margin-bottom:4px;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li#active a,
#nav-wrap .container ul li a:hover {
color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your markup it's really hard to tell .. do you have a link to your website?

Comment: #nav-wrap{ margin:0 auto; } should work

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav-wrap {
position: relative;
width: /*set width, can't be 100% obivously if you want it centered */
margin: auto;
}
```

This is a guess, we don't see any HTML , apply this to whatever is the container for the entire navbar

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the HTML structure, but this could work.

```
#nav-wrap .container ul {
  display:block;
  width:auto;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#topnav a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 11px 60px 60px 15px;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

i had to mess with the padding but this centered my nav bar in weebly